# What exactly is meant by "part of speech" (POS) in linguistics and NLP?

Tags: words, pos-tagging

I am learning about Arabic word morphology, and ChatGPT lead me to [this](https://nyuad.nyu.edu/en/research/faculty-labs-and-projects/computational-approaches-to-modeling-language-lab/research/arabic-natural-language-processing.html) which says:

> In Modern Standard Arabic (MSA), a complete part-of-speech tag set has **over 300,000 tags** (whereas English has about 50), and MSA words have 12 morphological analyses on average (English has 1.25 POS tags per word on average).

I said that's preposterous, and found another article, which ChatGPT later found, called [Arabic Part of Speech Tagging](https://cl.indiana.edu/%7Eskuebler/papers/arab.pdf), which says:

> Tagging words, in contrast, results in often unambiguous words but in the largest tagset of **993 complex tags**

It calls this one of the tags:

```
[CONJ +
FUTURE PARTICLE +
IMPERFECT VERB PREFIX +
IMPERFECT VERB +
IMPERFECT VERB SUFFIX MASCULINE PLURAL
3RD PERSON +
OBJECT PRONOUN FEMININE SINGULAR]
```

I found there are [36](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41150051/169992) POS tags for the Penn Treebank Project, but that is probably just for English.

So what exactly is a "part of speech" then? Is it basically the combination of all features of a word (thing separated by spaces)? Like the above example? In that case, there is no standard set of POS tags? It changes for each language?

I thought POS was a universal thing, but apparently it is not. What is POS then, how do you conceptualize of it across languages?

For example, these are listed as separate POS tags for Arabic:

- Emphatic Particle: Used to emphasize a statement or word.
- Future Particle: Indicating future tense (e.g., "سوف").
- Conditional Particle: Used in conditional sentences.
- Exception Particle: Used to express exception (e.g., "إلا").
- Causative Particle: Expresses cause or reason.

I would have thought that just "particle" was the POS, and the type of particle didn't add to the number. Just an example. It's basically some sort of categorization system, but I don't quite get what it's categorizing.

Comment: Again, this gets into the entire field of syntax.

Comment: POS **tags** in some database are not at all the same thing as parts of speech themselves. A tag set may be very badly designed, but that doesn't mean the language itself would have more than a few dozen actual POSs (probably most have at most a dozen). In particular, the POS tags there are including all the various inflections a verb might have, when they'd all be one POS: verb.

Comment: There are only 8 parts of speech: noun, verb, adjective, determinative, adverb, preposition, subordinator and coordinator.

Comment: @BillJ are you just joking or where did you get that concept from? It would be great if there were just 8.

Comment: There are indeed just 8. Any decent grammar will confirm that. For example, the finest grammar of the English language available today, CGEL (Huddleston & Pullum) [link](https://english109mercy.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/handout-8-1-parts-of-speech-copy.pdf) You're including sub-types of the 8 in your count. When attaching POS labels in a tree diagram, only those 8 are given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One purpose of parts-of-speech is to simplify grammatical descriptions. They group together words that behave in a similar way, and their behaviours can then be more easily described in rules. They are most commonly used in NLP (natural language processing), eg to implement syntactic analysis.

English pos-tags are a bit different from many other languages, as there are no case markers for nouns, and verb forms are usually compounds with auxiliaries.

If you want to describe subject-verb agreement, for example, you can look for a singular noun (NN) and a third-person singular verb (VBZ) or a past tense verb (VBD) by matching the pattern `NN VBZ|VBD`, ie a NN followed by either a VBZ or a VBD.

Part-of-speech taggs are assigned by a pos-tagger. These are programs that take a text and assign the most likely tag to each word (most words can have multiple possible tags: *light* can be a NN, a JJ (adjective), or a verb (VB)  (using the most common English tags). The actual tag depends on context:

- They turn the light_NN off
- I have a light_JJ suitcase
- Light_VB my fire

Different taggers operate on different principles, but most are probably using statistics and/or machine learning nowadays.

In the most basic sense a part-of-speech is "noun", "verb", or "conjunction", but for most language processing these labels are to coarse to be very meaningful, so they are enhanced with more specific subtypes adding further features, like number, person, tense. But for a morphologically-poor language such as English this is not very easy.

Comment: And adjective, adverb, preposition, determinative, subordinator, coordinator, -- 8 in all. What do you mean by "verb forms are usually compounds with auxiliaries"?

Comment: @BillJ Yes, there are more p-o-s than I listed. What I mean is that verbs in English don't really have many features expressed through morphology. "light" can be present or future ("will light"), so for the actual features tense, aspect, voice etc you have to consider the full verb group and not just the main verb. The term "compounds" wasn't chosen were well, that is how such verb groups are called at the company I work.

Answer (score 1):

"Part of speech" is only marginally recognized in theoretical linguistics, instead linguists deal in features, and then perhaps offer informal recognitions of traditional parts of speech in terms of features. In essence, a feature is a classification of a linguistic object as being in or out of a subgrouping in a language. Usually, features are thought to have substantive underpinnings which could be primarily semantic in syntax, but in morphology is often arbitrary lexical subdivisions. Computational views are completely different, and I think the 300,000 estimate comes from combinatorics of a bunch of independent features.

In fact, many Bantu languages have vastly more complex combinatorics, since verbs agree with subject in noun class (there are 20 classes plus 4 non-3rd persons), object markers (up to three, same 24 possibilities), two or three different tenses multipled by some clause-type distinctions (affirmative/negative; main clause / subordinate (4 subtypes)), passives, causatives, applicativs, reciprocals (and their combinations) and so on. Greenlandic would have infinitely many tags, under this view of "part of speech".